# Installing xelatex from yaml

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, yaml, xelatex

### Question

How can I modify my environment yaml (for a python setup) `environment.yml`, to automatically install `xelatex` on Ubuntu?

### Context

Currently my yaml consists of:

```
name: space
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - conda
dependencies:
- anaconda
- nb_conda
- conda:
  - numpy>=1.19
  - pytest>=3.0,<3.8
  - notebook
  - jupyter
  - nbconvert
  - matplotlib
  - ipykernel
  - tudatpy
  - nb_conda
  - scipy
- pip
- pip:
  - pdflatex
  - testbook
  - pyment
  - pdoc3
  - black
```

Which can be installed with:

```
conda env create --file environment.yml
```

and updated with:

```
conda env update --file environment.yml
```

And when I try to convert a jupyter notebook to pdf, the notebook throws the error `nbconvert failed: xelatex not found on PATH,` because xelatex is not installed (and added to PATH). According to this documentation, one can solve that, on Ubuntu platforms, with:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-generic-recommended
```

However, that is an additional manual step which is something I would like to avoid. How could I modify the `environment.yml` to do that?

Tangential: I was able to install it in the `.travis.yml` with:

```
before_install:
 - sudo apt-get update -qq
 - sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-latex-recommended texlive-latex-extra texlive-science
```

However that is something else than the `environment.yml`.

Comment: You can't run a `sudo apt-get` command automatically when creating your env. For one, it goes against the concept of an environment to make system wide installations. Secondly, it would be a severe security risk if yml files could contain (arbitrary) code that needs to be run with `sudo`

Comment: @FlyingTeller While that is true, it does not render the endeavor impossible. [texlive-core](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/texlive-core) seems to be available for conda, however it is woefully undocumented as its name does not match with any `apt` package and therefore it's unclear which parts of texlive are included.

Comment: Good idea, however it does not seem to include xelatex, I just tried it on a fresh env